# cakephp: Order by using counterCache

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I have two model.

Below Model descibe Relation between them.

```
class DebatePost extends AppModel {
var $name = 'DebatePost';
var $hasMany = array(
        'DebateComment' => array(
        'className' => 'DebateComment',
        'foreignKey' => 'debate_id',                
        'dependent'=> true,

        )
    ); 
 }


class DebateComment extends AppModel {
var $name = 'DebateComment';
var $belongsTo = array(
    'DebatePost' => array(
        'className'     => 'DebatePost',
        'foreignKey'    => 'debate_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        'counterCache' => 'no_of_comments'
    )
 ); 
}
```

And I created 'no_of_comments' field in debate_posts table.

And
In DebatePost controller,

```
$arrde = $this->DebatePost->find('all',array('order'=>'debat_posts.no_of_comments DESC'));
```

i follow above step two find debate_posts data orderby no of comments in debate_comments by using countercache.but didnt get any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'order'=>'DebatePost.no_of_comments DESC'
```